# Splitting code into modules (conventions)

Tags: python, python-3.x, conventions

So I've been searching for a bit and couldn't find anything on Google or PEP discussing this.
I am doing a project with `tkinter` and I had a file, that is part of a project, that was only 200 lines of code (excluding all the commented out code). While the entire file was related to the GUI portion of the project, it felt a bit long and a bit broad to me.
I ended up splitting the file into 4 different files that each has its own portion of the GUI.
Basically, the directory looks like this:

```
project/
        guiclasses/
                   statisticsframe.py
                   textframes.py
                   windowclass.py
        main_gui.py
        ...
```

`statisticsframe` has a class of a frame that shows statistics about stuff.
`textframes` holds 3 classes of frames holding textareas, one of them inherits Frame, the others inherit the first one.
`windowclass` basically creates the root of the window and all the general initialization for a `tkinter` GUI.
`main_gui` isn't actually the name but it simply combines all the above three and runs the `mainloop()`

Overall, each file is now 40-60 lines of code.

I am wondering if there are any conventions regarding this. The rule of thumb in most languages is that if you can reuse the functions/ classes elsewhere then you should split, though in Python it is less of a problem since you can import specific classes and functions from modules.

Sorry if it isn't coherent enough, nearly 3AM here and it is simply sitting in the back of my head.

Comment: This is one of those things which cannot be strictly defined. You have to use your gut feeling (which means, the more experienced you are, the better decisions you make), because it really depends on more things than one could put in words. Anyway, I would not say that the number of lines is very important, unless it is really extreme (I would not make many files with 3 lines each, nor do I like to have many of them with thousands of lines of code).

Comment: Anyway, this is primarily an opinion-based question and therefore I'd say off-topic on SO.

Comment: A lot of things are defined in PEP that often can be regarded as preference or opinion, like line length or space between brackets and what is inside them.
Also, to be fair, I asked if there are any conventions (even if not Python official) about this, rather than what people prefer.

Comment: Sure, and once they are defined e.g. in PEP-8, then they are no longer opinion-based ;) And what you are asking is not defined in a PEP, so the best answer you can get is that it is not defined, or many conflicting answers based on users' opinions - which is why such questions are off topic ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with `tkinter`, so my advice would be rather broad.

You can use any split into modules which you feel is better, but

- as readability counts try making names coherent and do not repeat yourself: `guiclasses` - your enire progarm is about GUI, and there obviously classes somewhere,  why repeath that in a name? imagine typing all that in in import, make it meaningful to type
- flat structure is better than nested, three modules do not have to go to submodule
- best split is across layers of abstraction (this is probably hardest and specific to `tkinter`)
- anything in a module shoudl be rather self-sufficient and quite isolated from other parts of the program
- modules should make good entitites for unit testing (eg share same fixtures)
- can you write an understandable docstring for a module? then it's a good one.
- try learning by example, I often seek wisdom for naming and package structure in Barry Warsaw [mailman](https://gitlab.com/mailman/mailman/tree/master/src/mailman), maybe you can try finding some reputable repo with `tkinter` to follow (eg IDLE?).

From purely syntatic view I would have named the modules as:

```
- <package_name>
   - baseframe
   - textframe
   - window
   - main
```

Comment: The entire project isn't about GUI, only those 4 files, for now. There are few more files that add the functionality needed for the GUI, like the statistics, that is why I chose `guiclasses`. It is a valid point nonetheless. 

Your idea about learning by example is actually a really good one, I'll look into mailman and IDLE.

Comment: Hope some of the clues will help! I'd just save some typing by naming `guiclasses` just `gui`, classes part looks redundant to me.

Comment: Also, write back here with tkinter examples, if you find any worth reviewing. Perhaps Spyder should be on a list too.